# exit application from fragment activity

Tags: android

I want to close the android application from fragment activity. Fragment layout contains two menus.one of the  fragment will display the list. When we click on the list it will display the details for list in Dialog Alert that alert box contains two buttons.if you click one button it will open another activity that activity will contains list. if we click the list it will open previous activity in the fragment activity.if you click back button from this activity it is not closing the app completely.

please give me good solution to exit the app from the situation

Comment: Call `Activity.finish`

Comment: If you're in the activity, just call finish();

If you're in fragment, call getActivity().finish();

Comment: its is again open the empty page, it is not going to home screen

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you activity managment is something like this:
A -> B -> A
And if you pressing back now it is not closing. 
You should watch to [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

So when you opening Activity A again you code should look like this:

```
    Intent a = new Intent(this,A.class);
    a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(a);
```

Comment: And then in that activity check for the flag, something like this in the `onBackPressed()`: `if(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) finish();`

Comment: I used the above code. still i am facing the same problem

Comment: @sowbar_sathik
Try this:
a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Comment: sowbar-sathik can you confirm if this solved your problem